# Facebook API Reporting - C#, RestSharp

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, restsharp

I am trying to download a report with my console application. There are a few things that I am having a hard time understanding with the facebook API.
 [image]

What is the hardcoded 1000002 about. If you hit this URL either in the browser of the Graph API Explorer you get a single entry that contains:

```
{
  "name": "Angus Shieh",
  "id": "1000002"
}
```

I need to download a csv file and according to:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.5
I need to download it using this url:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=<REPORT_ID>&format=<REPORT_FORMAT>&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

This works sort of in the browser, I can download a report but it only contains two fields, not a full report at all. I however am having a difficult time downloading this file with my code. I tried to create an HttpClient and navigating to that url, which didn't work.

What I would like to do is download a report for each of the campaign for each account programmatically. I will then use that data in a later step to populate a reporting database.

**Update:**
I have figured out how to download a report using the API.

**Step 1** - Call the endpoint that creates a async job.

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com"); // new client

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    request.Resource = "{version}/{campaign_id}/insights"; // campaind id is the <ad object>

    request.AddParameter("version", "v2.5", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.AddParameter("campaign_id", "6039201600172", ParameterType.UrlSegment); // needs a campaign id
    // the form post fields
    request.AddParameter("level", "ad");
    request.AddParameter("fields", "['campaign_name','ad_name','ad_id','reach','frequency','impressions','cpm','cpp','spend','social_clicks','unique_clicks','ctr','unique_ctr','account_name','actions','total_actions','website_clicks']");
    request.AddParameter("time_range", "{'since':'2016-04-04','until':'2016-04-04'}");
    request.AddParameter("time_increment", "1");
    request.AddParameter("access_token", accessToken);

    // EXAMPLE URL WHEN DONE
    // https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/6039201600172/insights 

    IRestResponse<Report> response = client.Execute<Report>(request);
    var report_id = response.Data.report_run_id; // report run id
```

**Step 2** - check that newly created job's status until it is done.

```
var reportPercent = "";

 while (reportPercent != "100")
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds
                // Next Request
                var checkReportStatusRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

                checkReportStatusRequest.Resource = "{version}/{report_id}"; // campaind id is the <ad object>

                checkReportStatusRequest.AddParameter("version", "v2.5", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                checkReportStatusRequest.AddParameter("report_id", report_id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                checkReportStatusRequest.AddParameter("access_token", accessToken);
                //request.AddParameter("access_token", accessToken, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                // https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/6042737300572/?access_token=EAAIe5FQupPkBAADZBTgqWDBTDHkoJ9k0HSQSu1PLpbBdPgKFhyvRtIMUXF0po06r8hRw1nbJOszznSNEh8OJW4XBeNxClZApeWoJ31QQDSn7KZC33PPY8Wazknu0ZC3mUnKGP0ZCa4OiuawLPsu8FhrLuGaNj4M4ZD
                IRestResponse<ReportStatus> responseStatus = client.Execute<ReportStatus>(checkReportStatusRequest);
                //var responseStatus = client.Execute(checkReportStatusRequest);
                reportPercent = responseStatus.Data.async_percent_completion; // report run id
                //var reportPercent = responseStatus.Content; // report run id
            }
```

**Step 3** - download your report.

```
    string url = "https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=" + report_id + "&format=csv&access_token=" + accessToken;

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
        wc.DownloadFile(url, @"C:\reports\page1.csv"); // download the file
    }

    Console.WriteLine("File Downloaded");
    //pause
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
I have figured out how to download a report using the API.

**Step 1** - Call the endpoint that creates a async job.

```
    var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com"); // new client

    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

    request.Resource = "{version}/{campaign_id}/insights"; // campaind id is the <ad object>

    request.AddParameter("version", "v2.5", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.AddParameter("campaign_id", "6039201600172", ParameterType.UrlSegment); // needs a campaign id
    // the form post fields
    request.AddParameter("level", "ad");
    request.AddParameter("fields", "['campaign_name','ad_name','ad_id','reach','frequency','impressions','cpm','cpp','spend','social_clicks','unique_clicks','ctr','unique_ctr','account_name','actions','total_actions','website_clicks']");
    request.AddParameter("time_range", "{'since':'2016-04-04','until':'2016-04-04'}");
    request.AddParameter("time_increment", "1");
    request.AddParameter("access_token", accessToken);

    // EXAMPLE URL WHEN DONE
    // https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/6039201600172/insights 

    IRestResponse<Report> response = client.Execute<Report>(request);
    var report_id = response.Data.report_run_id; // report run id
```

**Step 2** - check that newly created job's status until it is done.

```
var reportPercent = "";

 while (reportPercent != "100")
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds
                // Next Request
                var checkReportStatusRequest = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

                checkReportStatusRequest.Resource = "{version}/{report_id}"; // campaind id is the <ad object>

                checkReportStatusRequest.AddParameter("version", "v2.5", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                checkReportStatusRequest.AddParameter("report_id", report_id, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                checkReportStatusRequest.AddParameter("access_token", accessToken);
                //request.AddParameter("access_token", accessToken, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
                // https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/6042737300572/?access_token=EAAIe5FQupPkBAADZBTgqWDBTDHkoJ9k0HSQSu1PLpbBdPgKFhyvRtIMUXF0po06r8hRw1nbJOszznSNEh8OJW4XBeNxClZApeWoJ31QQDSn7KZC33PPY8Wazknu0ZC3mUnKGP0ZCa4OiuawLPsu8FhrLuGaNj4M4ZD
                IRestResponse<ReportStatus> responseStatus = client.Execute<ReportStatus>(checkReportStatusRequest);
                //var responseStatus = client.Execute(checkReportStatusRequest);
                reportPercent = responseStatus.Data.async_percent_completion; // report run id
                //var reportPercent = responseStatus.Content; // report run id
            }
```

**Step 3** - download your report.

```
    string url = "https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id=" + report_id + "&format=csv&access_token=" + accessToken;

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
        wc.DownloadFile(url, @"C:\reports\page1.csv"); // download the file
    }

    Console.WriteLine("File Downloaded");
    //pause
    Console.ReadKey();
```